# Decoding the base64 part in a string in Java

Tags: java, string, base64, byte

I have encoded into base64 using the Java class built in. But when I try to decode I am having some issues. This code should explain what is happening:

```
String secondhalf=text.substring(text.length() / 3,text.length() / 3* 2);
byte[] secondhalfByte = secondhalf.getBytes();
secondhalf = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secondhalfByte);
```

I am getting the error:

> cannot convert byte[] to String

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

To get an encoded string or a decoded byte[] use the following:

```
String secondhalf=text.substring(text.length() / 3,text.length() / 3* 2);

String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secondhalf); 
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
```

So you either want to encode your 'secondhalf' into a encoded string or then decode that into a byte[]